# Looking for a .NET Dijkstra component using Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, open-source-gis, .net, routing

I'm totally new to stackexchange and i'm in this beautiful informative place for one problem.
I'm a .net programmer and i need to write a program that reads a shapefile and performs routing operation. I'm looking for an open source solution.
Is there any idea?

Comment: Does the shapefile already have from-nodes and to-nodes assigned to it?

Comment: unfortunately not. Is it possible to make it in ArcGIS?

Comment: Are the ends of the polylines snapped to each other?  If so you could calculate FNODEID and TNODEID fields based on concatenation of x and y of the polyline's from point and to point respectively.  You should also consider an ID for the polyline itself, since the FID could change as a result of editing.  Once you have the necessary IDs, you can handle it as a [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) problem. See [resources](http://www.babelgraph.org/links.html).

Comment: yes. How to create these fields in ArcGIs or any other software? Does it need programming? Could u explain more, Plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the open source requirement isn't too strict (you already seem to accept Arcgis as part of the solution), you can also look at our RW Net solution (www.routeware.dk). It is a .NET component, which will import SHP files and let you do routing calculations. No need for adding fnode/tnode fields, since the component handles that internally.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, i have arcgis but i can't pay anymore. It Sounds Route Net 2.43 free version performs the job. Also i found TF.Net useful i.e reading shapefile and calculates shortest path, as described in documentation

Answer (score 4):

I would start by looking at [this implementation in C#](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2006/01/c-dijkstra-algorithm-implementation.html) along with the [DotSpatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/) libraries maybe?

Comment: It sounds i have to make graphs out of shapefile myself. Am i right? I was looking for a more direct way, not to handle this dirty things.

Answer (score 3):

Small advice: use [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) instead of Dijkstra, with a decent heuristic you'll get much better performance.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332466/how-does-dijkstras-algorithm-and-a-star-compare

Comment: You are extremely right :)

Comment: Thanks. but is there any implementation for that in .net using shapefile?

Comment: You should treat reading shapefiles and A* algorithm routing as two separate things. A* is usually implemented in a generic way so it can be reused for different purposes. As for reading shapefiles, take a look at SharpMap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138642/simplest-c-implementation-of-a-algorithm